# Brown leaves on pineapple plant

Tags: houseplants, watering, leaves

We've had a pineapple plant in the office for 2-3 weeks, situated in the centre of the room in good, sunny weather.  It's been regularly watered so that the soil is slightly damp, but no more.

The lower leaves have started to turn brown and, at the tips, crispy:
[image: Pineapple plant in new location]

In the past couple of days it's been moved to a new location to get a bit more sun, but I have no idea what's causing this --- is it down to overwatering?  Too much/little light?  Not enough love?

Comment: has the plant flowered?  they die after flowering...

Comment: @kevinsky I don't believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pineapples are in general appreciative of heat and light and humidity, however sudden changes can be upsetting to many species. The window location might be better for light, but architects often design heaters into window places which can mean hot dry air rising. This would not be good for pineapple which is a bromeliad, expecting water at leaves and roots.

It's a fairly large plant for that size of pot. The new location might just be a bit stressful causing some of the older leaves to mature and want to die off more quickly than you expect from previous behaviour.

In summary the plant looks healthy but is in need of a cleanup and repotting. Remove unsightly leaves. Give it a chance to become accustomed to the new higher light environment and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned about pineapple plants is the reason the leaves turn brown is that they store water and when they turn brown its from overwatering